# Directus Couldn't reach api error

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server

I tried installing directus on a ubuntu server and when I tried going to the admin page this error occurs:[API error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xj8d.png)

I tried modifying permissions for directories and files to be 755 and 644 respectively but the error still persists:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQtOU.png)

Is there a step I'm missing? I followed all the instructions in the [directus documentation](https://docs.directus.io/getting-started/installation.html#requirements)

Do I need to do a manual install?